# Android Facebook Api Crash

Tags: java, android

I integrated facebook login for android. Its working fine. But while testing I found a wierd issue.

```
with Android OS 4.2.1 with facebook app - no issues.
with Android OS 4.2.1 without facebook app - no issues.
with Android OS 2.3  with facebook app - app crashes while trying to sign in.
with Android OS 2.3 without facebook app - no issues.
```

Did anybody had such issues?

Please help

Comment: Can you provide LogCat output containing crash cause information?

Comment: Actually I did an alpha release so the device is not with me. How do I get the crash report?

Comment: connect device to PC and use LogCat view in Eclipse. Or use some apps like AndroidSystemInfo which allows you to save LogCat output directly from device

Comment: @user527759 That device is not accessible to me. So what I did was I created a virtual device with same android version and installed facebook app in that. Now but its not crashing in emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your project properties go to Android -> Project Build Target.
select Platform 2.3.

see if you have compilation errors.
if you do, it means you were using android code newer than that api